Is a recommendation letter from my PhD advisor unethical?
After finishing my Ph.D, I asked my advisor to provide me a recommendation letter for a possible future application, and they replied: "according to my standards it is unethical to provide recommendation to my collaborators."
Does that mean they refused to give it to me, or is it truly not useful?

Did you mean a letter to be placed in your possession or one they might send in the future?

Only your advisor can clarify what they mean.

In my possession

In my experience, recommendation letters are given to the person doing the hiring/admitting/etc directly, not to the applicant. Are you sure that isn't what your advisor is referring to: giving you the recommendation letter directly, versus writing a letter on your behalf to give to someone else?

If you want useful answers to this question I think you need to edit it to clarify exactly what the situation is. Someone is misunderstanding something here.

Please do clarify your situation, in line with comments and answer(s). That is, for one thing, being unwilling to give support to one's PhD students would be bizarre. On another hand, being unwilling to hand to a student the letter written supporting them would be absolutely typical in the U.S., for example. What, exactly, is happening with you? Also, the specific mention of "not writing letters for collaborators" is very hard to understand. Context?

I'll echo a comment of Brian Krause about how letters are sent to potential employers (etc.) rather than being given directly to former students. I hope you've misunderstood something.
Many places will almost require a letter from your thesis advisor, collaborator or not. Many posts here talk about the difficulty of getting by without such a letter.
My opposite view would be that it is unethical for them to deny you a letter if your performance was good. I hope you can work this out.
It would be appropriate to ask them to have a letter prepared so that, over time, they don't forget the needed details and can send a good letter. Losing track or losing contact can be a problem.
If the department has adequate clerical staff, a professor might place a letter with them to be sent at their request when you ask the professor to have it sent. The request would come from you to the professor and then to the department. Sometimes this is possible.
